# Firebase instead of SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, firebase, nosql

I have been using SQLite as my storage solution for my android applications. I want to be able add synchronization functionality to one of my apps, Firebase looks like a good solution but the problem is that I need to know if I am to use Firebase to sync data with the SQLite database or Firebase can work and totally replace SQLite. I know Firebase has offline persistence but while offline can it hold as much data as SQLite and are the queries as powerful?

Comment: As per Firebase offline capabilities documentation "By default, 10MB of previously synced data is cached." It claims that is has intelligent syncing capabilities. Unless you expect data storage higher than 10MB, you might as well just use Firebase. See documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)

Comment: Thanks, I needed an offline first solution and will be expecting more than 10MB so Firebase might not be the solution :(, the Realm mobile platform looks more like what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly this depends on the business rules for which the options are considered. So there will not be the "right" answer to this.

At least one of our team members was thinking along these lines. Here is our solution:

1. Do all transactional data locally on the SQLite as we do not need transactions to be across devices.
2. Sync the rest using Firebase.

(1) makes sure that we don't misuse Firebase's non-persistent offline availability of its client.

[The docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-handling-transactions-offline)
`Even with persistence enabled, transactions are not persisted across app restarts. So you cannot rely on transactions done offline being committed to your Firebase Realtime Database. To provide the best user experience, your app should show that a transaction has not been saved into your Firebase Realtime Database yet, or make sure your app remembers them manually and executes them again after an app restart.`

(2) make sure that we use Firebase's persistent offline nature to synch non-transactional data across devices once connection is (re)established.

[The docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities), `The Firebase Realtime Database client automatically keeps a queue of all write operations that are performed while your app is offline. When persistence is enabled, this queue is also persisted to disk so all of your writes are available when the user or operating system restarts the app. When the app regains connectivity, all of the operations are sent to the Firebase Realtime Database server.`

This way we achieve a state acceptable within our use.

"can it hold as much data as SQLite and are the queries as powerful?" no and no if powerful is translated as "[transaction](https://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) across devices", by definition of Firebase being a remote database.